# Preencher Segundo Input automaticamente quando se preenche o Primeiro

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Eu tenho um `input` que vou dar o nome de `input-1`, e lá vou inserir isto: `12:00`

Ao ter um segundo `input` que vou dar o nome de `input-2`, é possível ao inserir no `input-1`: `12:00`

Ele no `input-2` possa preencher automaticamente o tempo que coloquei no `input-1` mas com mais duas horas.

**Exemplo**:

Coloco `10:00` no `input-1` e no `input-2` aparecer: `12:00`.

É possível fazer isso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim,

Você deve adicionar um *event listener* no `input-1` dos tipos

- KeyDown(quando a tecla é pressionada mas não solta) ou,
- KeyUp (quando a tecla é solta) ou,
- KeyPress (quando a tecla é pressionada)
- ou ainda Blur (quando sair do input)

E fazer este disparar uma função que trate os dados do `input-1` e insira eles no `input-2`.

Tendo como exemplo o seguinte código:

Javascript com JQuery para facilitar visualizar o *binding* do evento:

```js
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('#input-1').keyup(function (e) {
        var patt = /([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2})/;
        // Testando se o valor digitado já é algo como nn:nn
        if (patt.test(e.target.value)) {
            var strsplit = e.target.value.split(':');
            var hora = Number(strsplit[0]) + 2;
            var min = (strsplit[1]);
            var stringfinal = '';
            // ex. se hora = 24 então vira 00, se hora = 25 então vira 01;
            if (hora > 23) {
                hora = hora - 24;
            }
            if (hora < 10) {
                stringfinal += '0' + hora;
            } else {
                stringfinal += hora;
            }
            stringfinal += ':' + min;
            $('#input-2').val(stringfinal);
        } else {
            // Faz nada...   
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input-1" type="text">
<input id="input-2" type="text">
```

Isso deve dar o efeito planejado, a função que fiz foi bem básica e pode ser muito melhorada, é mais uma prova de conceito.

Os eventos podem ser aferidos mesmo sem jQuery. 
Mais informações podem ser encontradas em [Input na MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input%20Input%20na%20MDN) e [KeyUpEvent na MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keyup)

Espero que isso responda sua pergunta.

Comment: Obrigado ! Era mesmo isto que queria, obrigado mesmo !

Answer (score 4):

Você poderia criar uma função para pegar o valor valor do primeiro `input` e definir uma segunda variável para somar, no seu caso, com o valor de `2`. Assim ele pegará o valor, e somará com o número definido na variável.

```js
function calc()
{
  var a = "2";
  var b = valor.value;

  total.value = parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b) + ':00';
}
```

```html
Valor: <input type="time" id="valor" onkeypress="calc()"><br/><br/>
Total: <input type="time" id="total">
```

Neste caso eu coloquei o  `:00` apenas para seguir o seu exemplo, mas ele é irrelevante, caso não seja preciso utilizar o mesmo.

Comment: Dude. Que cena mais básica e eu p'rali com `match` p'ratodo o lado. Bravo :)

Comment: Como faço para colocar um zero antes, da 1 da manha até as 9?

Comment: +1 btw, o `input` de Valor está type="teStbox" e mesmo assim está funcionando. Então deve funcionar também com type="text" (que ele pega por padrão) apenas né? Vc sabe se é possível utilizar o mesmo exemplo para type="time" (com aquelas caixinhas duplas de escolha do tempo, do HTML5), ou só se a entrada for de texto mesmo? De  qualquer forma valeu, já vai ser útil pra mim.

Comment: @gustavox ele funciona com o type="text" e com type="time". Ele pega o valor do input, independente do type. Editei a resposta com um exemplo de time.

Comment: Muito bom, vai ser bem útil, valeu!